# Create template with variables and convert to PDF

Tags: templates, pdf, docx

I have a client, that sells stuff and has to send a PDF with variable information (customers name and address, generated numbers...)

Currently we get a couple of templates (about 10 at the moment) for that from our client - in .docx We take those, fill in the variables and convert it to a PDF for sending to the customer.

As you can imagine, this is really a pain for us, because we always have to fix some formatting issues in there.

Is there a "best practice" on how to do this? We really don't want to work fix word files and it should also be very easy for our client. I was thinking about some kind of WYSIWYG editor that creates a PDF out of html?

Does anyone has any other suggestion or experience with this issue?

Comment: So to assume this is a programming question, if it were me, I'd pick a language and make webforms for your client to fill in their data. There are libraries that convert HTML to PDF apparently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf - maybe start there?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The data that gets filled in like customer name etc. gets filled in by our application. we get the template from our client and I actually need a way without the need to process a word document, but also a way, where my client does not  need to learn how to write html ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what options you have for languages that have any libraries that convert Word Document templates into PDF. I think you'll either need to transform those templates into HTML for the client and plug it into a web form perhaps. Otherwise, maybe there might be something somewhat achievable by using scripting in Word.